# Excel Cross Referencing

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Got an interesting problem that seemed trivial at first...

I have a table in the following format:

```
USER | QUESTION | ANSWER 
========================
1    | 1        | A
1    | 2        | B
1    | 3        | D
2    | 1        | A
2    | 2        | B
2    | 3        | A
3    | 1        | B
3    | 2        | A
3    | 3        | D
```

I am trying to generate a pivot table that looks something like:

```
             | QUESTION (2)  
-------------+---+---+---+---
QUESTION (1) | A | B | C | D 
-------------+---+---+---+---
           A | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0
           B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
           C | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
           D | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

That is, semantically, "people who answered question A with answer B and also answered question X with answer Y", for each possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the way you've got your data set up can't be laid out that way; because all the answers come under one column.

When designing raw data each row should represent a discrete element, in this case that element is a single instance of a test or survey being taken. So all data about that instance should exist in one row.

Amend your data so that you have a single row for each user and a column for each question.

```
USER | Q1 | Q2 
==============
1    | A  | A
2    | D  | B
3    | C  | D
```

Next build your pivot table and put Q1 in the rows and Q2 in the columns, with a count of user in the Values.

[image: Example]

The only issue is that if an answer doesn't show up for a question in the source data there isn't an entry for it in the pivot table, but that pretty clearly means no-one answered with that combination.

**An alternative**
You want to build a matrix, so the answer above shows you how to do that, but you have more than two questions and a matrix only works for two series. Instead try this:

1. Make your table as above, with all the question columns you want
2. Make your pivot table, but this time drop all the questions into the Rows field
3. In the PIVOTTABLE TOOLS tab, DESIGN, press Report Layout and select Tabular
4. Open that dropdown again and select Repeat All Item Labels

Now you'll have a discrete table of all actual combinations and the counts of how often those combinations came up.

[image: Tabular pivot table]

Comment: Thanks. So it's not possible to do lookups via the USER field?

Comment: @DerFlatulator, you could build a matrix out of vlookups but it would be clunky and fixed; you'd have to rebuild it if you added more data or questions. These options are dynamic and reliable, and require very little computing power because they don't rely on volatile functions that refresh whenever anything changes.

Comment: So current plan is to change the server PHP code to generate CSV files in the format you specified. However could you give a pointer if I needed to go with VLOOKUPs instead?

Comment: Thinking about it, VLOOKUPS wouldn't work; you'd need to use [COUNTIFS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) instead. You would need to build a matrix with COUNTIFS that say something along the lines of `count the User column if Q1 = A and Q2 = A and Q3 = A`, and then makes a different version for *every* combination! Plus COUNTIFS don't work in older versions of Excel. Basically you're best shot at doing what you need is with the pivot tables. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Awesome. Just got it all together (using the first method mentioned). Thanks muchly.

Comment: You're very welcome :)